# Dart private package (source code is exposed for all clients issue)

Tags: dart, encryption, package, private

I have a private package (Dart) that contains sensitive logic but I created an interface that is only exposed, I want to share this library with clients but I don't want the logic to be shown (I can see the files from cache when importing the library in other projects).

What is the best practice to solve this issue please? Thanks!

I tried to use the structure of lib/src -> contains all logic and lib/[name_of_package.dart] which has the export line.

On other projects I was able to see the only exported class but on cache folder I can see the whole structure even lib/src, I don't want clients to see it.

Comment: Write it in platform code, ship it as a binary.  Oh, and you must support all platforms.  And all versions of the ABI.  Oh, and even then, they can single-step through your code.  In other words, don't bother.  Use legal restrictions, not technical restrictions.